# Securing/Authticating WebLogic JNDI handles

Tags: weblogic, jndi

is there an accepted best practice for securing access to a Weblogic JNDI (JDBC Specifically) services from external apps?

Out primary motivation is  trying to stop people from accidentally pointing QA code at production machines, but obviously there is the question of securing the port from unwanted visitors (other hosts on the internal network) as well.

Idea would be that an arbitrary client can't just connect to :
`t3://importantprodhost.mycompany.com:7001`

and get hold of one of the remote JDBC/JNDI stubs that are proxies to our databases

I did find this [link](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/weblogic_chap17/index1.html?page=5) which seems to be related, but I was hoping not to have run everything as a `WebLogic.runAs()` call.

My guess was that one could only expose the JNDI service over a HTTPS and authenticate with a certificate (which wouldn't be on the QA machines), but haven't found a concrete/simple example, so I don't know if this would actually work.

*Please assume for the purposes of this question that we **need** access (i.e we can't turn it off) - we'd just like to authenticate it, and that we can't deploy anything network level such as  a firewall to solve the problem.*